# Natural join query results show the same as the column header

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a query using a natural join.
EX:

```
SELECT 'num_tracking', 'id_token', 'cde_status', 'adr_mail_city', 'num_ssn' 
FROM T_PR_ENRL 
NATURAL JOIN T_PR_ENRL_BOARD
```

The results for each column are repeating the column header for each column selected.  So for the Num_Tracking column, it repeats Num_Tracking for the entire column instead of the actual results for the column.  This column is from the T_PR_ENRL table.  I don't see where the problem lies.  Can someone help please?

**NUM_Tracking**
  NUM_Tracking
  NUM_Tracking
  NUM_Tracking

Comment: `'num_tracking'` is a literal string, you need either no quotes `num_tracking` or double quotes `"num_tracking"`

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes `'` around text indicates a string literal and not a column name.

Remove the quotes and it should work.

If you have a particular need for case sensitive column names (it would be very unusual if you did) then you can wrap the column name in double quotes `"column_name"` - but this is not typical practice.